How do you connect this tub with a hose type drain to a trap?
As part of a bathroom remodel, we are looking at installing a bathtub with a strange drain setup. The tub has the overflow and main drain connected with this black plastic tubing that ends as a corrugated hose that needs to be connected to the drain trap somehow. The instructions are not very helpful on the topic:

This installation guide does not include details of waste
connection.Final decision about installation of waste connection
should be taken by a contractor

This diagram is provided, clearly the tubing should not just be loosely laid inside of the drain pipe. Is there an accepted, correct approach for this?
Would I just stub out the drain from the trap and use a flexible coupling ("Fernco" coupling)? Or would a slip joint be better? I do have access from underneath, which might satisfy access requirements for the slip joint, but it would still seem like a poor choice. Is there a preferred / standard approach to these types of tub drains?
This is located in the USA, and the tub is for sale (and on display) at a major big box store, so this is not a funky, one-off import.
Link to the tub item page
Link to the instructions


A corrugated tube for a tub drain doesn't look like the best idea... I'd think that would collect all kinds of "gunk" over a relatively short time.

Where in the world are you? If you are in the US, that is an unusual tub. Are you importing it? That drain style may be acceptable in other places but is not suitable for use in the US.

@longneck This is located in the USA, and the tub is for sale (and on display) at a major big box store, so this is not a funky, one-off import.

It's still an unusual design, to say the least. It looks like something intended to be temporary, or a retrofit into a shower, or ot perhaps into an outbuilding where the grey water will just drain to outside, rather than being a standard fixture. Can you give us specific make/model so we can investigate that?

(Being on display in a big-box store doesn't mean it can't be a special-purpose solution.)

@keshlam - links added to the question. This is just being advertised as a normal bathtub in the store and the website.

It's specifically being advertised in the "freestanding and claw foot" category, which is not exactly normal these days except in high-style installations -- and those are expected to be engineered around or to be going in where that work has already been one. If you really want a walk-around tub, fine, but that has additional costs. If you just want a normal built-in tub, this is probably , the wrong product for you.

@keshlam please see my question, I am not asking for opinions on this type of tub, just want to know what the appropriate way of connecting this to a drain system is.

"Just want to know what the appropriate way of connecting this to a drain system is."
Install a floor drain, with a trap below the floor.
I would highly recommend making the entire bathroom (or at least the entire area around the tub) a "wet room", with sealed floors that act as a basin sloped inward so any spilled water also goes into that drain. That also helps protect you a bit if that floor drain gets backed up, since you can't count on the tub doing so. If you're going to make the additional effort, you might as well get full benefit out of it to offset the disadvantages.

Yep, sounds basically like a clothes washer drain to me!

Thanks! But you don't mention how you would suggest making the actual connection between the tub and floor drain. Can you update the answer to include that?

I'd do exactly what the diagram shows, just run the hose into the drain, possibly strapping it in place somehow.
